# Biq Query - Count

Tags: google-bigquery

I have table that displays 
ID employeename Supervisorname

Need to display another column  CountD: count of employee for the direct supervior,CountI which shows the count of employee indirect

Snapshot shared[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6idk.png)

Tried Count (*) over partition by Supervisorname but didnot help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Try below script

```
#standardSQL
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;

CREATE TEMP TABLE input AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'A' employee, 'X' supervisor UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B', 'X' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C', 'X' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'X', 'F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Y', 'F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'F', 'G'
);

CREATE TEMP TABLE ttt AS SELECT supervisor, employee FROM input; 

LOOP 
  SET (rows_count, run_away_stop) = ((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt), run_away_stop + 1);

  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE ttt AS 
  SELECT supervisor, employee FROM ttt UNION DISTINCT
  SELECT t1.supervisor, t2.employee 
  FROM input t1 JOIN ttt t2
  ON t1.employee = t2.supervisor;

  IF rows_count = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM ttt) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;  
END LOOP;

SELECT t1.*, 
  IFNULL(direct_employees, 0) AS direct_employees, 
  IFNULL(all_employees, 0) AS all_employees 
FROM input t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT supervisor, COUNT(1) direct_employees 
  FROM input GROUP BY supervisor
) t2 ON t1.employee = t2.supervisor
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT supervisor, COUNT(1) all_employees 
  FROM ttt GROUP BY supervisor
) t3 ON t1.employee = t3.supervisor
ORDER BY 1;
```

it returns desired output

[image]

To apply to your real table

1. Remove `CREATE TEMP TABLE input AS ( ... )` statement
2. Instead of `input` table use your real table reference as `your_project.your_dataset.your_table`
3. Also, take attention to `run_away_stop > 10` expression - it takes care of loop running not more that 10 times - you can tune this number based on how deep hierarchy in your data

As an option - you can try use Array instead of Temp table as in example below

```
#standardSQL
DECLARE rows_count, run_away_stop INT64 DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE ttt ARRAY<STRUCT<supervisor STRING, employee STRING>> DEFAULT [];

CREATE TEMP TABLE input AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'A' employee, 'X' supervisor UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'B', 'X' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'C', 'X' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'X', 'F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Y', 'F' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'F', 'G'
);

SET ttt = ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT supervisor, employee FROM input);

LOOP 
  SET (rows_count, run_away_stop) = (ARRAY_LENGTH(ttt), run_away_stop + 1);

  SET ttt = ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT * FROM (
      SELECT supervisor, employee FROM UNNEST(ttt) UNION DISTINCT
      SELECT t1.supervisor, t2.employee 
      FROM input t1 JOIN UNNEST(ttt) t2
      ON t1.employee = t2.supervisor
    ));

  IF rows_count = ARRAY_LENGTH(ttt) OR run_away_stop > 10 THEN BREAK; END IF;
END LOOP;

SELECT t1.*, 
  IFNULL(direct_employees, 0) AS direct_employees, 
  IFNULL(all_employees, 0) AS all_employees 
FROM input t1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT supervisor, COUNT(1) direct_employees 
  FROM input GROUP BY supervisor
) t2 ON t1.employee = t2.supervisor
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT supervisor, COUNT(1) all_employees 
  FROM UNNEST(ttt) GROUP BY supervisor
) t3 ON t1.employee = t3.supervisor
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. but I get this error  "Script variable ttt exceeded  the size limit of 1048576 bytes" have atleast 8K records in my table

Comment: which version you used - with temp table or array? looks like array - so you should use temp table version

Comment: please try and let me know. array version has size limitation obviously :o)

Comment: thank you.. I tried array earlier .. Used temp table now.. It works perfectly fine Checked the last 'View Result'.. thanks a lot.. But was wondering, how do I get the final query result as I get 'View Results' multiple times as there are multiple scripts.. Have created temp table XYZ across select t1.* , ifnull.... statement but didnot work.... Appreciate your response..

Comment: the last statement in the script is the final result - the result that is expected based on image in your question